# How can I get more in depth in path following?

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, path, dwa-local-planner

I wanted to learn more about ROS, path planning, following etc.
I made my own path following algorithm, a simple PD controller that follow waypoints. On a path msg it didn't worked really well, but it worked, so:

I wanted to know where can I get more information about it, how do the local_planner algorithms that we have in ROS works? How they compute velocity for the robot? I know that they are open source, I have taken a look at the code but couldn't really figure out.

Can someone tell me what articles, videos, etc that I could see to get more in depth in this? hanks.